# How to create a redirect for WordPress posts with PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

https://github.com/markjaquith/page-links-to

This is a simple WordPress plugin to redirect when you click a post to custom page.

How can I use this function or a function in wordpress to change a post id into a redirect link with a PHP function (basically skipping the user interface)?

Would I use one of these functions for this plugin (either to open in the same page or a new tab)?

Or is there another way where I don't have to use this plugin or it's functions and use a wordpress built in function?

```
function set_link( $post_id, $url ) {
        return $this->flush_links_if( (bool) update_post_meta( $post_id, self::LINK_META_KEY, $url ) );
}


    /**
     * Tell an custom URL post to open in a new tab
     *
     * @param int $post_id post ID
     * @return bool whether anything changed
     */
function set_link_new_tab( $post_id ) {
        return $this->flush_targets_if( (bool) update_post_meta( $post_id, self::TARGET_META_KEY, '_blank' ) );
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are wanting to do because there are many ways to interpret the question.

Comment: I want to make post id ie 27 to go to www.example.com/folder

Comment: A permalink for each post but using a function to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [wp_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) function to do this.

For your example:

```
function example_redirect() {
    if ( is_page( 27 ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'www.example.com/folder' );
        die();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'example_redirect' );
```

Comment: This works with pages, but it doesn't seem to work with posts

Comment: `is_page` won't work with posts, you'll need to use `is_single()` for that. So if you need to check for either, the if statement would look like: `if ( is_page( 27 ) || is_single( 27 ) )`

Answer (score 1):

You can turn Wordpress post ID to a permalink with get_permalink function which is build in function in WordPress. Documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

Comment: Could you give me a coding example of how to use it?